# Is it a must that logic converter must be used with breadboard?

Tags: iot

I am working on a project that requires me use logic converter as my nodemcu esp 32 is 3.3V and my sensor is 5V. I got my logic converter soldered and I am trying to assemble the parts together but I am stuck now as I am not sure is it a must to use logic converter with breadboard? I am sorry if my question sounds too dumb for I am a newbie and this is my first time working on IoT project. Any help/suggestion will definitely be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A breadboard is merely a convenient way to prototype circuits. That is, it makes it very easy to create temporary electrical connections in order to make sure that what you're building/designing works, before you make it into a more permanent part.

It may help to review the fundamentals of why a breadboard works, as discussed in the "using the breadboard" of [this link](https://herlaar.net/b3it/b3it-kit/hooking-things-up/). Remember that a hole on the breadboard is just an entryway to a rail which creates electrical connections. It is often much neater to use a breadboard instead of a series of alligator clips or the like.

If you wish to make your project more permanent, you make choose to use soldered wires, [prototyping board](https://www.bc-robotics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/3x7-1.jpg), or even design your PCB. Custom PCBs and prototyping boards would both have various components soldered to them to complete the circuitry.

There are various ways to achieve the necessary electrical connections to complete an electronics project. A breadboard is merely a convenient way to do this, and has the advantage of being easily to disassemble.

All you "need" is a proper electrical connection between your components. A breadboard is one way to achieve that, but not the only one.